# Utf8 encoding mysql query not working

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a problem with a mysql query. This is the code:

```
session_start ();
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("wordpress_97") or die(mysql_error());

$names=mysql_query('set names utf8');

$tempnewpw = md5($tempnewpw);

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE wordpress_97.tUsers SET passwort = '$tempnewpw' WHERE tUsers.UserID = '$theuserid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

> Yes I know that I shouldn't use the mysql_ functions but it's just testing..

And this is the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATEÂ wordpress_97.tUsersÂ SETÂ passwort =Â 'pwinmd5'' at line 1

I can't get away these Â...

The database shouldn't be the problem - other querys work without problems with the same structure.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what happens if you delete the whole line and write the query again, don't copy paste it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @AlexAndrei Thank you this worked, but now I see that the string gets encoded wrong - doesn't matter what I type in the string will be "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e".

Comment: I added an answer for both your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the line and re-type it.
Most likely those are characters carried over from copy-pasting.

Regarding your second question, `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` is the `md5` hash of `null` or `nothing`, a zero-length stream of characters.

On this line

```
$tempnewpw = md5($tempnewpw);
```

Make sure that `$tempnewpw` exists and has a value, I should suggest also that you use different variables instead of over-writing them.

Comment: The re-typing of the query helped! And I've seen, that my form submit function had a little mistake in it -> I wrote metod="post" instead of method... Thanks for your help with the query!

Answer (score 1):

Try this use `mysql_set_charset`

```
session_start (); # not use for the DB query's 
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw') or die(mysql_error());

mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db); # add this

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("wordpress_97",$db);
//$names=mysql_query('set names utf8'); --- remove 
if (!$db_selected) { 
    die ('Database access error : ' . mysql_error());
}
else{
    $tempnewpw = md5($tempnewpw);

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE wordpress_97.tUsers SET passwort = '$tempnewpw' WHERE tUsers.UserID = '$theuserid'") 
    or die(mysql_error());  
}
```

**In html**

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: I already have the meta tag and the 'mysql_set_charset' doesnt' change anything...

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add this line in your html head tag:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Word for editing.  It introduces funny characters such as hex A0, which through some conversions becomes `Â` (A-hat and a space), as seen in your text.

I hope you don't have any accented letters; I suspect they have been mangled by other things -- such as failure to be consistent in `CHARACTER SET`.